# How to skip code in loop?

Tags: list-manipulation

There is some box [a,b] and each box[a,b] have elements like

```
box[1, 1] = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10};
box[1, 2] = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10};
box[2, 1] = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10};
box[2, 2] = {d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10};
box[3, 1] = {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10};
box[3, 2] = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10};
```

next, I made order[x] generated in a random sequence.

```
Do[order1[x] = RandomSample[Range[3], 3], {x, 3}]
Do[order2[x] = Table[RandomSample[Range[2], 1], 3], {x, 3}]
Table[order[x] = 
  Flatten[Table[{order1[x][[a]], order2[x][[a, b]]}, {a, 3}, {b, 1}], 
   1], {x, 3}]
```

Based on the above, I want to work following code.

```
    Do[newbox[a, b, x] = {}, {a, 3}, {b, 1, 2}, {x, 3}];
Do[{s = RandomSample[box[#[[1]], #[[2]]], UpTo[5]];
     drop = RandomSample[s, UpTo[2]];
     (*!!*)
     newbox[#[[1]], #[[2]], x] = 
      Flatten[Append[newbox[#[[1]], #[[2]], x], drop], 1];} & /@ 
   order[x];,
```

when it's order[x][[1]], I don't want only this (*!!*) code to be executed.
(ex:
If order[x] ={`{{2, 2}, {1, 1}, {3, 2}}`, {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {2,
1}, {1, 2}}},

So,I try to take apart only order[1],
I would like to have the following.

```
Do[newbox[a, b] = {}, {a, 3}, {b, 1, 2}, {x, 3}];
bag = {};

drop1 = RandomSample[box[2, 2], UpTo[5]];
box[2, 2] = DeleteElements[box[2, 2], 1 -> drop1];
bag = Append[bag, drop1]
bag = Flatten[bag, 1]
drop2 = RandomSample[bag, UpTo[2]]
bag = DeleteElements[bag, 1 -> drop2]



drop1 = RandomSample[box[1, 1], UpTo[5]];
box[1, 1] = DeleteElements[box[1, 1], 1 -> drop1];
bag = Append[bag, drop1]
bag = Flatten[bag, 1]
drop2 = RandomSample[bag, UpTo[2]]
bag = DeleteElements[bag, 1 -> drop2]
newbox[1, 1] = Flatten[Append[newbox[1, 1], drop2], 1]


drop1 = RandomSample[box[3, 2], UpTo[5]];
box[3, 2] = DeleteElements[box[3, 2], 1 -> drop1];
bag = Append[bag, drop1]
bag = Flatten[bag, 1]
drop2 = RandomSample[bag, UpTo[2]]
bag = DeleteElements[bag, 1 -> drop2]
newbox[3, 2] = Flatten[Append[newbox[3, 2], drop2], 1]
```

When these are made into a LOOP syntax,
What code should I add to specify order[x][[1]] and skip newbox[#[[1]], #[[2]]] = Flatten[Append[newbox[#[[1]], #[[2]]] , drop2], 1] codes?

I’d like to ask you for your help

Comment: why can't you use an `If` to check? Your code is kind complicated to follow. But you say you do not want to evaluate something when some condition is true. So try to use `If`

Comment: Of course I have tried everything I can think of with If, but it didn't work, so I am asking here.

Comment: Haven't we already answered questions equivalent to this?

Comment: Your code doesn't run without errors, so it's difficult to know what the right answer should be. Your code also looks much more complicated than it needs to be. For example I *think* that you can define `order` like this: `order = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {3, 3, 2}]`. You would then access elements with `Part` instead of function application, but I don't see why you want function application anyway.

Comment: I recognise that I am asking similar questions.
I wrote my question in the abstract, so even when I received some answer I could not apply it to the code I was actually running because I was not familiar with Mathematica.

Comment: Then what I'd suggest is ask your question in terms of what you want the answer to be rather than in terms of a specific implementation choice. Almost certainly you don't need nor want to use an `If` in this situation. Best way to do this is to provide the inputs you have and show us the expected output. Yes, you'll need to generate the expected output by hand, but without it, it's often difficult to interpret the question. It's also best to "dumb down" the question by removing all inessential details. So, you don't need to give us all your code and functions, just create a simplified example.

Comment: So, you didn't need to show us how you generated `order`, because that's not germain to answering your actual question. You could give us 2 `box` expressions and a smaller `order` table and then show us the desired result. Best if you don't even give us the "real" desired result, but some result that's easy to interpret. Like, we don't need to know what your actual processing looks like, just represent it with a dummy function, `f`.

Comment: I'm not even sure the `box` expressions are relevant.

Comment: Since I can't execute your code without errors, I'm just inspecting it, and maybe the answer to your question is as simple as replacing `{x, 3}` as your `Do` iterator with `{x, 2, 3}`.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it looks like you want to skip columns not rows. You can have multiple iterators in `Do`. Have you tried that?

Comment: You're making it more complicated. Stop showing us your implementation. Show us before and after. Get rid of the random stuff (we can add that back in later). I just have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: We have some boxes. We're going to randomly select some stuff from some of the boxes. We're going to use that to update the boxes and, at the same time, create newboxes. Maybe just try putting into words how the boxes should be updated and how the newboxes should be created.

Comment: Maybe use pseudo code instead of trying to write actual code. Like... `for each box do this: pick up to 5 elements randomly from the box, delete those elements from the box, create a newbox such that...`

Comment: In part of your code you have `newbox` taking three arguments (e.g. `newbox[#[[1]], #[[2]], x]`), but later you have it only taking two (e.g. `newbox[3, 2] = Flatten[Append[newbox[3, 2], drop2], 1]`). This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Okay, you're conflating `[]` with `[[]]`. It's going to be very difficult to make progress if you can't even describe your data structures properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it even runs. Do all of the same setup, and for your `Do` loop:

```
Do[
  drop1 = RandomSample[box @@ order[orderIdx][[itemIdx]], UpTo[5]];
  box[Sequence @@ order[orderIdx][[itemIdx]]] = 
    DeleteElements[box @@ order[orderIdx][[itemIdx]], 1 -> drop1];

  bag = Join[bag, drop1];
  drop2 = RandomSample[bag, UpTo[2]];
  bag = DeleteElements[bag, 1 -> drop2];

  If[
    1 < itemIdx,
    newbox[Sequence @@ order[orderIdx][[itemIdx]]] = 
      Flatten[Append[newbox @@ order[orderIdx][[itemIdx]], drop2], 1]],

  {orderIdx, 3}, {itemIdx, 3}]
```

I didn't try to clean up all of the unnecessary stuff you're doing; I just wanted to see if I was even understanding the question.

Comment: Thank you for your additional comments.
I have prepared an empty list for newbox[a, b] and bag, respectively, when I run the programme.
Do[bag[orderIdx]={},{orderIdx,3}].
Then it did not work very well.

I prefer the existing way (using "box[#[[1]], #[[2]]]" instead of "box @@ order[orderIdx][[itemIdx]]"),
Is it not possible to work it this way?

Comment: Regarding your question about using `box[#[[1]],#[[2]]]` instead...Sure you can do that, but we should figure out how to even get this working before worrying about such details,.

Comment: Regarding "it did not work very well"... How so? What went wrong?

Comment: Regarding `Do[bag[orderIdx]={},{orderIdx,3}]`... What the heck is that all about? I didn't know you wanted 3 bags. I guess I still don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: A bit more my actual code is box[1, 1] ={a1, a2, a3, a4, a5....} instead of {{a1,{1,1}},{a2,{1,1}},{a3,{1,1}}....}, It's like {2,{1,1}},{10,{1,2}},{23,{1,3}}..... So, bag = Join[bag, drop1] becomes bag = Append[bag, drop1]. I made Do[bag[orderIdx] = {}, {orderIdx, 3}]; at the beginning because I need to repeat it many times, but as I looped through the expression, the {} came off and I faced problems with DelateCases and Append not working properly in the later expressions

Comment: I sometime use text translation so my English may be wrong

Comment: The 3 in {orderIdx, 3} and the 3 in {itemIdx, 3} I will actually have them loop in larger numbers.

Comment: May I use your answer to create a ASK Question?

Comment: Yes…………………………..

Answer (score 1):

Taking a stab...

Given

```
order = Table[Subscript[t, i, j, k], {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 2}]
```

[image]

We can iterate over it with in a `Do` loop, and if we want to skip the first column, we can just adjust the `Do` iterators.

```
Do[
  Print[someFunc[order[[row, col]]]],
  {row, 3}, {col, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

The `Print` is just there to force an output I could paste in here.

Now, there are probably better ways to do this rather than use a `Do` loop, but since I don't really understand the semantics here, I'll refrain from making suggestions.